# Product Url As catalog/product/view/_ignore_category/1/id/

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite

Recent day , when i am uploading any product in bulk, its url is generated as `catalog/product/view/_ignore_category/1/id/.....`

**1. Search enginer optimisation is set as below**

Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Categories - Yes

Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Products - Yes

**2. Reindexing and chache refeshed but issue is not resolving.**

Kindly help i am using mangento 1.9.0.1.

Answer (score 2):

**Try Below Steps:**

- Take Backup of core_url_rewrite table
- Truncate the table
- And run re-indexing.

Comment: Thanks A lot Satya. Great Its Work , it also solved my all url issue... thanks Jai hind